# How do I upload a custom playlist cover image with Spotify API

Tags: node.js, express, spotify, put

I'm on a private node.js project.
On the server there should be an endpoint to update the cover image of a specific playlist. Inside this endpoint I've got this code:

```
let playlistID = '7fOfY.......G5RFK3z';              // ID of already created playlist
let imgFile = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRg.......AgICAg';         // data:image/jpeg;base64
let spotifyAccessToken = 'DHdhw3.......DHdfLS8';     // valid access token


let options = {
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/' + playlistID + '/images',
    headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + spotifyAccessToken,
         'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
    },
    body: imgFile
}

request.put(options,(error, response) => {

    if(response.statusCode === 202) {
         console.log('Upload cover');
    } else {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
```

In the terminal it always fails and there is no cover image in Spotify. Anyone knows what is wrong? What can I do to fix this problem? https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/upload-custom-playlist-cover/

EDIT:

Response object looks like this:

```
{"statusCode":400,
    "body":{
        "error": {
            "status": 400,
            "message": "Bad request."
            }
        },
    "headers":{
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "cache-control": "private",
        "max-age=0",
        "access-control-allow-origin":"*",
        "access-control-allow-headers":"Accept, App-Platform, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, Retry-After, Spotify-App-Version, X-Cloud-Trace-Context",
        "access-control-allow-methods":"GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH",
        "access-control-allow-credentials":"true",
        "access-control-max-age":"604800",
        "content-length":"72",
        "date":"Fri, 24 Jan 2020 09:29:49 GMT",
        "via":"1.1 google",
        "alt-svc":"clear",
        "connection":"close"
        },
    "request":{
        "uri":{
            "protocol":"https:",
            "slashes":true,
            "auth":null,
            "host":"api.spotify.com",
            "port":443,
            "hostname":"api.spotify.com",
            "hash":null,
            "search":null,
            "query":null,
            "pathname":"/v1/playlists/7fOf.....FK3z/images",
            "path":"/v1/playlists/7fOf.....FK3z/images",
            "href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/7fOf.....FK3z/images"
        },
    "method":"PUT",
    "headers":{
        "Authorization":"Bearer BQDBBS2T......CZVtcz70",
        "Content-Type":"image/jpeg",
        "content-length":0}
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it fail with - does the access token have the ugc-image-upload scope that's something worth checking and is the JPEG less than 256KB?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes the token got the ugc-image-upload, playlist-modify-public and playlist-modify-private scope. The JPEG is 100KB.

Comment: I had problems when doing those with my C# Spotify Client at https://github.com/RoguePlanetoid/Spotify-NetStandard but it seems to do the same as yours, the image as base 64 encoded etc. Would be good to know what Http Response Code you're getting

Comment: I've added the response message above. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same 404 Bad Request and couldn't find out why for like 2h.. Turns out I had a `\n` at the end of the body text, because I imported the base64 data from a text editor that seems to add a `\n` automatically on save.

The body text must be without the proceeding `data:image/jpeg;base64,`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.base64decode.org/ which I found from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51445491/9472445) may be useful to ensure your payload is decoding correctly to an image, you can put the base64 string in a text file and upload it to this site to see if it decodes to your desired image.

Omitting "data:image/jpeg;base64," from the start of the base64 string, if you haven't done so already, may also help.

Answer (score 0):

I really struggle several hours to do this with axios and fetch but the base64 strings I was getting with them were not a valid one.

I then tried to use an old trick with the native XMLHttpRequest and everything works fine now. I'm downloading pictures from Spotify before uploading them to new playlist.

```
// Legacy code not optimized used to gather Spotify cover img in valid base64 format
function getEncodedPictureFromURL(url, uploadCallback) {
    const xhRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhRequest.onload = function () {
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            uploadCallback(reader.result)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhRequest.response)
    }
    xhRequest.open('GET', url)
    xhRequest.responseType = 'blob'
    xhRequest.send()
}

export default {
    async updatePlaylistCover(playlistId, coverUrl) {
        const callback = (base64cover) => {
            // Spotify does not need leading data type
            const bytesNoMetadata = base64cover.split(',')[1]
            
            // Axios object already knowing Spotify base URL and access token in the headers
            request.put(`playlists/${playlistId}/images`, bytesNoMetadata, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' }
            })
        }
        getEncodedPictureFromURL(coverUrl, callback)
    }
}

// ex
// await getEncodedPictureFromURL("PLAYLIST_ID", "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706c0000bebb992c70080d1de4f43fc55708")
```